# android and web app in kiicloud can I sync their data in kiicloud?

Tags: android, parse-platform, synchronization, backend, kiicloud

I am trying to understand how to create an android app and web app that syncs their data in kiicloud or any other backend provider. I know that kiicloud has a SDK for android and JS, but JS is just for mobile apps because it is just javascript, they do not have support for server side code, so my question is can I do this in any backend provider?

I have made an app  with a local sqlite database, but I have not used an beckend provider such as parse, kinvey or kiicloud.  I now want to make an android App / web app that should create/update on both platforms and syncs so both have the new/updated items, the app should also work offline.

Help very much appreciated

Comment: Please I need help on in this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KiiCloud and other MBaaS providers such as Parse share many similarities. You can create a high level interface (MBaaSInterface.java) that exposes the most common operations (save object, retrieve object, etc) and then create implementations of the interface for each MBaaS (eg. KiiClodImpl.java, ParseImpl.java, etc).

In order to see similarities/differences between Kii, Parse and StackMob you could use [this basic migration guide](http://documentation.kii.com/en/guides/ios/migration-guide/) to get a feeling of it.

For an Android app I advice to use the MBaaS provider specific SDKs (not REST).

BTW KiiCloud does support [server extensions](http://docs.kii.com/en/guides/serverextension/) as other providers but for Android you don't need this or javascript, just use the Android SDKs which should be fairly mature.

Best. Good luck!